# Binding not working when using ko.mapping with 2 models

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have been trying to get a drop down select working on a page with a table using knockout bindings. I have managed to get both the drop down and table working correctly when there is only one on the page and I am not using mapping options in the knockout binding plugin.

However when I use the mapping options either drop down or table works incorrectly. I haven't been able to find anything online that helps the problem.

I have created a jsFiddle here for further information:

The html is as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-curved">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Team</th>
    </tr>
  <!-- ko foreach: History -->
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Team1"></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

and the js is:

```
$(function () {
  var reasons = [
    { Id: 1, Reason: "Late", SafeName: "late" },
    { Id: 2, Reason: "Road Works", SafeName: "road_works" },
    { Id: 3, Reason: "Later", SafeName: "later" },
  ]

  var history = [
    { Name: "John", Team: "Team1" },
    { Name: "Peter", Team: "Team1" },
    { Name: "Simon", Team: "Team2" }
  ]

  function GetData(){
    return [history, reasons];
  }

  function ReasonModel(data, parent) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, parent.Reasons)
  }

  function DelayModel(data, parent) {
var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, parent.History)
  }

  function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    var mapping = {
      reasons: {
        create: function (options) {
          return new ReasonModel(options.data, self);
        }
      },
      history: {
        create: function (options) {
          return new DelayModel(options.data, self);
        }
      },
    }

    self.History = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.Reasons = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.SelectedReason = ko.observable();

    self.GetHistory = function(){
      GetData().done(function(result){
        ko.mapping.fromJS(result, mapping, self);
      })
    }
  }
  var vm = new ViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
  vm.GetHistory();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/372221/vg6kf3pw/14/

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Appologies. I made a typo there I have fixed it to use `<tr></tr>` because that is the convention the application follows.

Comment: I think your problem could be that you return an array in the `GetData` method, and not an object. you should return `{ reasons: reasons, history: history }` instead of `[ reasons, history ]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had many errors/mistakes in your fiddle. First of all, here is a [working one](http://jsfiddle.net/2zwLt2cv/1/).

Here are your errors.

- The jsfiddle was not properly set up. To properly set it up, choose the library `Knockout 3.4` at the Javascript settings. After that you don't need to reference directly the js file. Also, you had no reference to the mapping plugin at all. Finally you don't need the jQuery document ready wrapping, especially not when jQuery is not even referenced.
- The mapping plugin maps from objects to objects, which by default have to have matching property names, which are case sensitive. So you have to provide a proper source from `GetData`.
- The `GetData` method didn't return a promise-like object, so no `done` callback. In my version I used some mocking for that.
- Due to the invalid HTML, `ko` was unable to process the virtual binding nodes, so I needed to add the correct `tr` wrapping around the `th` tags.
- You had incorrect bindings: `Team` is correct instead of `Team1`, and in `optionsText` the correct getter should return `SafeName` (I guess).

**UPDATE**

Your updated fiddle had these errors.

- Several misspelling or wrong cases of words. You can see these basic issues when running your fiddle while Dev Tools (F12) is open. Console will give you the exception from ko bindings.
- You applied bindings **before** you called the mapping. So this resulted that the bound properties were undefined that time, since those are created on-the-fly by the mapping plugin (this is one of the design reasons for example why I don't use it). So first you have to call `GetHistory`, then `ko.applyBindings`.
- In your child items' constructor you passed for example `parent.DelayHistory` to `ko.mapping.fromJS` as third parameter, so actually the plugin pupulated the properties into the `observableArray` instead of the actual item. In fact you don't even need the `parent` reference in this case (unless you have other reasons in your real code).

Comment: That was really helpful. I have tried to integrate the changes into my solution and while I have no actual errors now none of the data displays. I have updated my fiddle to show the more complicated solution, the URL is: `http://jsfiddle.net/372221/vg6kf3pw/14/`. Sorry about the jsfiddle problems I am very new to using it as a resource.

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you for aiding me!